# Accounting for different dimension images in CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a comments section that loads images of different users from a database. The images are uploaded to the server and stored 100% of their original size (I don't care about this as this website is just a test project).

I am having a problem when it comes to displaying the images in the comments box - I want the images to retain their original proportions, but I am using CSS to blanket-resize all user avatars so that they fit nicely in the comments section.

Here is a screenshot of my problem (imagine that a user could upload an image of themselves that is in portrait orientation and my CSS would cause it to look horrible):

[image: screenshot of problem]

CSS:

> ```
> /* ROUNDED AVATARS */ 
> .avatar-frame{border: 2px solid #c7b89e;}
> .avatar-frame,.avatar-frame img{ 
> width: 150px;
> height: 120px;
> -webkit-border-radius: 30px; /* Saf3+, Chrome */ 
> border-radius: 30px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */ 
> /* -moz-border-radius: 30px; Disabled for FF1+*/
>  }
> ```

I have tried using 50% for the width and height of the image, but this will be different for each image featured surely?

ASP:

> ```
> <%-- Comments Box --%>
>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
>     DataSourceID="CommentsDataSource" Height="167px" Width="325px">
>     <Columns>
>       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
>         <ItemTemplate>
>         <table>
> <tbody>
> <tr>
>     <td rowspan="3"><div class="avatar-frame"><asp:Image ID="Image1" CssClass="templateimagefield"
>    NullImageUrl="~/img/no_image.jpg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#
>    Eval("AvatarURL","~/Account/{0}")%>'/></div>
>         </td>
>     <td><h2><%# Eval("BookCommenter")%></h2></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td><h2><%# Eval("TagLine")%></h2></td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td><%# Eval("CommentBody")%></td>
> </tr>
> </tbody> </table>
>
>         </ItemTemplate>
>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
>     </Columns>
>
> </asp:GridView>
> ```

So yes any ideas about what I can do?

Cheers in advance,

Adam

Comment: Why are you using tables?

Comment: Just using them as a lazy way to structure my comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximize browser compatibility, only specify one dimension (probably width, according to your screenshot), and the image will be scaled to that width while preserving the height-to-width ratio.

hurrtz's max-width max-height is probably better if you are concerned about the possibility or the outcome of images being unusually tall (say, 150px wide by 1000px high).

Answer (score 2):

You can go for max-width and max-height.

```
max-width: 150px;
max-height: 120px;
```

But you should know that the capability of your browser to shrink or expand images are fairly bad. It's just not the job of the browser to be good at that. You might want to consider resizing the images beforehand, with ASP, delivering them to a special folder on your webspace that is there to serve resized thumbs. Then your browser will always show images in best quality and you don't have to go for a CSS-solution that might not always serve as the best solution.